# A responsive thumbnail grid in Drupal 7 node

Tags: views, 7, chaos-tool-suite, theming, media

How to create a responsive thumbnail grid in Drupal node? I need simple thumbnail grid with description under the pictures, without expanding image. Something like this [example](http://www.directindustry.com/prod/jdsu-21029.html). All thumbnail containers should have the same size, say 210px x 210px, but size of images can be diffferent. I installed a lot of modules, include Views, Chaos tool suite, Picture, Brilliant Gallery, but it mostly suitable for image galleries, not for simple thumbnail grid.

Is there method to create responsive picture grid without editing templates or altering core? (i.e. adding code directly in the body of 'Article' or 'Basic page' content, while text format is full HTML) I have read *Views* and *Views Fluid Grid* modules manual, but got no idea how to use them for this task, not even sure whether this will be suitable for this purpose.

Comment: If there is no module for it, then use the tools that Drupal provide. The example you refer to can be implemented with just Views and CSS.

Comment: Yes, I also prefer CSS-only way to create this, without extra modules.

Comment: If you're stuck with the CSS I'm afraid you're in the wrong place to get help - this is a site for Drupal-specific questions, whereas CSS is obviously not. If there's something re Drupal you need to know could you edit the question to make it clear what that is?

Answer (score 1):

When you get to this level of customization you need to start considering creating your own page/node templates.

If I was doing this,  my pages for this content would get their own content type,  then I would create a corresponding page template.

These links may be helpful:
https://www.drupal.org/node/982122
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7

Inside that page template, I would then load the raw data for the node, using [node_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7)  and then access the fields directly and put them inside the appropriate markup.

Comment: I ended up with setting up thumbnail grid, based on Bootstrap v3.3.2 by adding html directly into a node body, its much easier and does not require extra modules.